# Facebook Ads Api: Create paused adgroup/ad

Tags: facebook, api, ads, adgroup

I'm trying to make the call to FB API to create a new adgroup and ad, with adgroup status set to 9 (adgroup paused).

However, my new adgroup goes through following phases: 
 - adgroup_status: 4 (pending review) and then
 - adgroup_status: 1 (active)

What is going on there?

To make things worse - after the review process is done, I can easily make another request in which I pause the adgroup. So...

Cheers

Comment: Could you post your api call and the response? Hard to guess what's going on since your description sounds like you're doing things correctly.

Comment: Well, I don't have the code here on my computer, since I'm doing it on work... But you can take the most simple, demo request and try it out (one that you can find on Ads API Docs). It works perfectly fine with making new ads. It also works perfectly fine when I'm modifying an ad (but only those that are already approved). I'm pretty sure you can only set its status to paused once it's Active (which means it has been approved, since after creation, it has status 4 - pending review).

Comment: Making me do some work here, huh :). I'm getting the same result so maybe you should file a bug... or a "new feature request". Of course, the short-term fix is to create it and immediately pause it. Then again, I've seen some google evidence that paused adgroups might not get approved. Alternatively, if you have some flexibility in where to stick the adgroups you could put them in new campaigns which are paused. Creating paused campaigns works for us.

Comment: Also, I am able to set status to paused just after having created it. I.e. while the status is 4, pending review.

Comment: Hm... when i try it after creation, it keeps its status (pending) and after approval, it simply ignores me :)... my app has the campaign clone func, which is why i need to create paused ads... (in case original ad is paused)... thx for answering and strange to hear that yo'll able to pause them while in status 4... i tried without success... i guess i'll be posting feature requests to fb team ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked some time ago, answering for other readers.

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup/

Note: Ad groups are in pending state after creation until they are approved (or rejected). Once an ad group is approved, it will be in running state. If you would like an ad group not running after approval, you can create the ad group in a paused campaign, and then resume the campaign when you are ready to run the ad group.